# Finding out corresponding call of Microsoft.ExchangeService in Graph SDK for .NET

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Please help me to find out the corresponding call of Microsoft.ExchangeService(EWS) in Microsoft,Graph. I am using .dotnet core/c#

1. ExchangeService.GetRooms()
2. ExchangeService.ResolveNames()
3. ExchangeService.FindAppointments()

Answer (score 0):

I will share links into the Graph API documentation where you can find C# code for Graph SDK

1. Get rooms

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-list-all-the-rooms-defined-in-the-tenant

2. Resolve names

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-people?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#examples

3. Find appointments

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example

Resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-exchange-web-services-api-mapping

Comment: Thanks a lot #user2250152. Let me raise specific request for the APIs. I will share the result in this thread.